# How do I tell search engines via JSON Structured content that the content is free but hidden behind a login and password?

Tags: seo, metadata

That's it, my costumer has a website that has free content for professions like doctors and attorneys, that have a number they can prove they're from the proffession.
The content is hidden behind a registration that asks for that number, but aside from that, the registration is free.

I'm going to create preview articles for the website, so search engines can index titles and content previews.

From the research I've done, I found that for paywalled content, there is a isAccessibleForFree property that can be set to false, but how do I tell search engines that it's behind a "Free paywall"?

More specifically, what's the markup for telling them the content is free but not available without a login?

Answer (score 1):

> More specifically, what's the markup for telling them the content is free but not available without a login?

The **isAccessibleForFree** property is exactly what you need. Its purpose is to explain that the content is not directly accessible, regardless of whether this is due to the fact that you need to log in. Here is an example implementation provided by Google:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Article headline</title>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "NewsArticle",
      "headline": "Article headline",
      "image": "https://example.org/thumbnail1.jpg",
      "datePublished": "2025-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
      "dateModified": "2025-02-05T09:20:00+08:00",
      "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "John Doe"
      },
      "description": "A most wonderful article",
      "isAccessibleForFree": "False",
      "hasPart":
        {
        "@type": "WebPageElement",
        "isAccessibleForFree": "False",
        "cssSelector" : ".paywall"
        }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="non-paywall">
      Non-Paywalled Content
    </div>
    <div class="paywall">
      Paywalled Content
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The rest of the details could be found on their website: [Structured data for subscription and paywalled content](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/paywalled-content)

Comment: But, should I set it to false even though it is indeed free? There's no Paywall, only the need for login